# Cannot access <a> element created after page load using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, href, prop

I have a site which has an  element with a specific id. I would like to get the href attribute using jQuery. I am trying to do the following:

```
alert($("#id").prop('href'));
```

But it says 'undefined'. I tried setting the timer function as well as using jQuery's delay(), but the result is the same, although I can see that the element is there when the alert pops up. What is the problem?

Comment: How can we know if you don't provide a full example that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: Why do you expect `$("#id").prop('href')` to access an element that doesn't exist yet?

Comment: Better put in a fiddle to see also the mark up. Are you sure is everything ok there? Try with an $('#id').attr('href') and also be sure that exist the id="id" on a <a> tag

Comment: I cannot give you a full example since the initial HTML does not contain the <a> tag with the specific ID. But with Firebug I can see that it is indeed there a few seconds after page load. The id attribute exists and attr() results the same as prop().

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can assure that JS works after HTML is loaded by wraping it into `document ready`. I've never used `prop`, but `attr` is awesome to get attributes. The example I provided should work.

http://jsfiddle.net/mJzr8/

```
$().ready(function() {
    alert($("#id").attr("href"));
});
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that this was the first thing I tried. The problem is that the element is not in the initial HTML body but it is (probably) dynamically created by another script.
It is my understanding that .prop() is supposed to replace .attr() which is deprecated in the newest version of jQuery (it still works though, they both yield the same output).

Comment: Are you sure that newly created element is in the same page but not in an iframe?